# Distribution App cannot install in iOS 10

Tags: xcode7, ios10

An IPA file is generated from Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014) and I would like to install it onto an iPhone running iOS 10, but nothing happens after I click the install button.

I uploaded it to dropbox using Betabuilder for iOS apps.

That IPA file can be installed on iOS 8.x and iOS 9.x. I tried searching for this issue online and I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Betabuilder for iOS apps need following files

1. App's Icon
2. Project.ipa
3. index.html
4. manifest.plist

The problem i cannot install app in iOS 10 is I forget to add project name in manifest.plist. But apps can be installed in iOS 9,8.

Please see the screen shot below.

[image]